# After MacOS High Sierra install, localhost fails and apache has syntax errors

Tags: high-sierra, apache, php

After upgrading to MacOS High Sierra, I haven't been able to access my localhost. I tried restarting Apache, but it still didn't work. So I did `apachectl configtest` and got this error message:

> httpd: Syntax error on line 544 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf:
>   Syntax error on line 8 of /private/etc/apache2/other/+php-osx.conf:
>   Cannot load /usr/local/php5/libphp5.so into server:
>   dlopen(/usr/local/php5/libphp5.so, 10): Symbol not found: _environ\n 
>   Referenced from: /usr/local/php5/libphp5.so\n  Expected in:
>   /usr/sbin/httpd\n

Line 544 of my httpd.conf file is
`Include /private/etc/apache2/other/*.conf`

The +php-osx.conf is an alias to entropy-php.conf, and line 8 of that file is
`LoadModule php5_module        /usr/local/php5/libphp5.so`

The remaining lines of entropy-php.conf are:
LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/php5/libphp5.so

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>

    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps

    <IfModule mod_dir.c>
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

I am using Apache/2.4.28 (Unix) and PHP 5.6.30.

Everything was working fine until the update. I have searched online for any solution this issue, but to no avail. Someone posted a similar question here a couple of years ago regarding the same syntax error, however, he didn't provide enough details or any follow-up regarding his setup, and no solution could be offered: [Mac apache not working - apachectl configtest errors](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/218598/mac-apache-not-working-apachectl-configtest-errors)

Comment: PHP 5.6.30 is **not** included in High Sierra! If you use a custom installation you should add the source (e.g. [PHP for OS X](www.php-osx.liip.ch) or brew/MacPorts) and the set-up guide you followed (e.g. coolestguidesontheplanet.com)!

Comment: Thank you for your response @klanomath. It has been a couple years since I set up my home development server, and the setup guide I followed starts with the assumption that when you start apache, you can access localhost, which I cannot. As High Sierra comes with php7.1, I'd prefer to upgrade my setup to that rather than staying with 5.6. I know I can install it using `brew install php71`, but what else would I need to do?

Comment: You don't have to install php71 with brew necessarily because macOS 10.13 comes with PHP 7.1.7 by default. My impression is that a lot of web developers have problems with 10.13 because Apple OS installer apparently ignores some custom set-ups while upgrading. Therefore I always ask them which 3rd party packages of PHP|Python|etc. they installed previously and which external set-up guide - each with a slightly different configuration/philosophy - they followed in the past.

Comment: [Upgrade to PHP 7.1 or 7.2 on macOS High Sierra or on OSX 10.6 – 10.11](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/upgrade-php-on-osx). Don't follow the instructions but check the comments! You probably have to comment out `LoadModule php5_module` in  +php-osx.conf.

Comment: When I type `php -v` though it shows I have PHP 5.6.32.  Why didn't the update change that to 7.1?

Comment: Because your PATH probably favors your older php (probably in /usr/local/bin). You can get the path of the "favored" php with `which php`. Apple's php is /usr/bin/php and the version is 7.1.7 (`/usr/bin/php -v`).

Comment: I tried commenting out `LoadModule php5_module` but then I get a new error with apachectl configtest which says `Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69146/discussion-between-klanomath-and-paul-brady).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here an (old) 3rd party PHP probably from entropy.ch was installed to /local/usr/bin/. The Sierra httpd.conf was modified to work with the different PHP (and virtual hosts).

While updating to macOS to High Sierra, the Sierra httpd.conf was backed up to httpd.conf.sierra, a new High Sierra httpd.conf was installed and gained control, but won't work with the custom PHP5.

After backing up the High Sierra httpd.conf to httpd.conf.high_sierra:

```
sudo mv /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf.high_sierra
```

reactivating the httpd.conf.sierra:

```
sudo cp /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf.sierra /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

uncommenting the httpd.conf line

`#LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`

and changing the version number from 5 to 7 so that it reads:

`LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so`

renaming the custom /local/usr/bin/php to php5:

```
sudo mv /local/usr/bin/php /local/usr/bin/php5
```

replacing the soft link /private/etc/apache2/other/+php-osx.conf (linking to /usr/local/php5/entropy-php.conf) with the High Sierra default /private/etc/apache2/other/php7.conf

and removing any reference to the custom PHP5, `apachectl configtest` was OK and Apache worked again - now with Apple's PHP7.